# Android Studio with gradle built classes.jar is empty

Tags: android, gradle, project, android-studio

I already success including my sub project lib to my main project, but I seems can't build my sub project lib, so I can't import it in my script.

when I look into directory **/build/exploded-bundles/** after build everything

I found **MyAndroidProjectStickyScrollViewItemsUnspecified.aar**, along side with **ComActionBarSherlockAxtionBarSherlock440.aar**, which both have similar dir structure, both contain :

- **assets** (dir),
- **res** (dir),
- **AndroidManifest.xml**,
- **classes.jar**, and
- **R.txt**

like this

```
MyAndroidProject
|- .idea
|- MyAndroid
|  |- build
|  |  |- exploded-bundles
|  |  |  |- ComActionBarSherlockAxtionBarSherlock440.aar
|  |  |  |- MyAndroidProjectStickyScrollViewItemsUnspecified.aar
|  |  |     |- assets
|  |  |     |- res
|  |  |     |- AndroidManifest.xml
|  |  |     |- classes.jar
|  |  |     |- R.txt
|  |  |- res
|  |  |- sources  
|  |- src
|  |- build.gradle
|  |- MyAndroid.iml
|- gradle
|- project-lib
|  |- StickyScrollViewItems
|     |- build
|     |- src
|     |  |- main
|     |     |- gen
|     |     |  |- com.emilsjolander.components.stickyscrollviewitems
|     |     |     |- BuildConfig.java
|     |     |     |- Manifest.java
|     |     |     |- R.java
|     |     |- java
|     |     |  |- com.emilsjolander.components.stickyscrollviewitems
|     |     |     |- StickyScrollView.java
|     |     |- res
|     |     |- AndroidManifest.xml
|     |- build.gradle
|     |- StickyScrollViewItems.iml
|- build.gradle
|- MyAndroidProject.iml
|- gradlew
|- gradle.bat
|- local.properties
|- settings.gradle
...
```

but while the **ComActionBarSherlockAxtionBarSherlock440.aar**'s classes.jar contain the following package:

- **android.support.v4.app**
- **com.actionbar.sherlock**
- **META-INF**

the **MyAndroidProjectStickyScrollViewItemsUnspecified.aar**'s classes.jar is empty

here the settings.gradle of the root project

```
include ':MyAndroid', ':StickyScrollViewItems'

project(':StickyScrollViewItems').projectDir = "$rootDir/project-lib/StickyScrollViewItems" as File
```

here the build.gradle of MyAndroid

```
import groovy.transform.Field

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.snowdream.android:android-async-http:0.0.2'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.2'
    compile project(':StickyScrollViewItems')
}
```

and here is the build.gradle of StickyScrollViewItems

```
import groovy.transform.Field

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}
```

what should I do so I can use

```
import com.emilsjolander.components.stickyscrollviews.R;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear of what you trying to achive, but most likely you should use @aar package instead of library project:

`settings.gradle`

`include ':MyAndroid'`

---

`\MyAndroid\build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.0.0'
}
```

There is no resources for this library:

[image]

But classes is not empty, if you add library as maven dependency. Please, check if it's help.

[image]

If you need to modify library sources, than update library sources it looks like author added gradle support recently.

Comment: Thanks, yes it may be added recently, but now i can include it using build.gradle, thanks @plastiv, upvoted and marked as correct, once again thanks